# How do I register a class for use by quartz scheduler in an eclipse web project?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use Quartz Scheduler in a web project that sends out emails to users at preset intervals. I would happy to be able to print out simple "hello world" statements at this point.

This is the code for the application that I would like to run.

```
package testing;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class QuartzTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("MAIN!!!!");
    try {
        // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
        JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
                    .repeatForever())            
            .build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        // and start it off
        scheduler.start();
        Thread.sleep(60000);

        //scheduler.shutdown();

    } catch (SchedulerException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and this is the job that is to be called:

```
package testing;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloJob implements Job {

public HelloJob() {
}

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
  throws JobExecutionException
{
  System.err.println("Hello!  HelloJob is executing.");
  System.out.println("HellowJob is executing");
}
  }
```

this is my quartz.properties file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = QuartzTest
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

and last but not least this is what I have added to my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Quartz Initializer Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-file</param-name>
        <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now, I am quite sure that the project is able to detect and read my quartz.properties file, but I have no reason to believe that the project (i.e. the server) knows anything about QuartzTest.java. I have not registered the class anywhere and likewise it is never called. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is great ! You have already bootstrap the Quartz successfully .

What are missing is that you have to define which jobs to run at which time .  You can do it by configuring [XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/plugins/xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.html) in `quartz.properties` . This plug-in will load paticaulr XML files that are defined by you to add jobs and schedule them with triggers when the quartz scheduler is initialized . (Refer [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd) for its schema definition )

In `quartz.properties` , add the following properties:

> org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class
>   =[org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/plugins/xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.html) org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = **quartz-config.xml**
>   org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true

Then in the **quartz-config.xml** :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <job-scheduling-data
            xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
            version="1.8">

            <schedule>
                <job>
                    <name>MyScheduledJob</name>
                    <group>MyScheduledGroup</group>
                    <description>Testing</description>
                    <job-class>testing.HelloJob</job-class>
                </job>

                <trigger>
                        <cron>
                                <name>HelloJobTrigger</name>
                                <job-name>MyScheduledJob</job-name>
                                <job-group>MyScheduledGroup</job-group>
                                <!-- It will run every 5 minutes -->
                                <cron-expression>0 0/5 * * * ?</cron-expression>  
                        </cron>
                  </trigger>
            </schedule>
    </job-scheduling-data>
```